# Mexican Spanish translation for box sticker

Tags: traducción, méxico, hispanoamérica

I've translated a couple of sentences from English into Spanish for a sticker I'm creating, and I'm not sure if the translated text is quite right for an audience of Mexican Spanish speakers.

The original English sentences and their current translations are provided below:

- Your device requires an activation code. = **Su dispositivo requiere un código de activación.**
- To activate your device, you must enter the activation code printed on your receipt. = **Para activar su dispositivo, debe introducir el código de activación impreso en su recibo.**
- If you do not have an activation code or have misplaced your receipt, please visit [URL] or call ### for assistance with device activation. = **Si no tiene un código de activación o ha perdido su recibo, visite [URL] o llame al ### para obtener ayuda con la activación del dispositivo.**

Please advise as to how I can improve my translations for an audience of Mexican Spanish speakers. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with @walen, your sentences are perfect, native speaker would not have done it better. A very very minor improvement would be changing "tiene" for "dispone de" in the last one, but I don't know how would it sound for a Mexican speaker, as I am from Spain.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo -  Good point, maybe it's a tiny bit pompous to a Mexican ear.  But Mexicans are so tolerant of awful translations, and this one is very nice indeed.

Comment: I am not Mexican, but I am spanish speaker and I see it perfectly

Comment: It looks fine to me also! Since asking for general corrections is off-topic here, it would be best if you [edit] to indicate what your specific doubts are.

Comment: Native speaker weighing in: *tiene* is exactly the word we would use in Mexico. The sentences are written perfectly. Good job.